# How to make table in given Div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

can you please tell me how to make table in div using jquery > I am getting data from server regularly after a few duration .I need to show on one column

```
<div id="realTimeContents" class ="left realtimeContend_h" style="width:100%;">
    </div>




  function createTable(){
                                 var content = '<table>'
                                 content += '<tr><td class=result></td> <td    
                                 class=result2></td></tr>';
                                 content += '</table>'
                                 $('#realTimeContents').append(content);
                             }
```

Used like that

```
     $('#realTimeContents').find('.result').append(result);
    $('#realTimeContents').find('.result2').append("Naveen");
```

But every Time it create a table .I think this is bug? I need to show data on one column?

Answer (score 0):

create table once -

```
function createTable(){
 var content = "<table>"
 content += '<tr><td class="result"></td></tr>';
 content += "</table>"
 $('#realTimeContents').append(content);
}
```

and update result with this -

```
function nativePluginResultHandler (result){
   $('#realTimeContents').find('.result').text(result);
}
```

Comment: @John Yes, you can call `createTable()` on page load i.e `document.ready`

Comment: I try like that but not getting the result ..I need to show different things on different column .But fail to get result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#btnClick").click(function(){
$("#realTimeContents").append("<Div>" + $("#txt").val() + "</Div>");
});
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/nFdtJ/